# how the process functions on linux?

Tags: linux, unix

I m a begginer with linux and I will learn the process function.
I don't understand what this code does exactly.
Can any one help me?

```
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    int nproc=0; // nombre de fils
    int link=1; // qu'est-ce qu'on link ?
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        pid_t pid=fork();
        switch(pid) {
            case -1: perror("Erreur"); break;
            case 0: execlp("gcc","gcc","-c",argv[i]); break;
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        link=link && WIFEXITED(status) && (WEXITSTATUS(status)==0);
    }
    if(link) {
        char **args;
        args=(char**)calloc(argc+1,sizeof(char*));
        args[0]="gcc";
        for(i=1;i<argc;i++) args[i]=f(argv[i]);
        // la fonction f remplace .c par .o 
        args[argc]=NULL;
        execvp(args[0],args);
    } else {
        printf("Erreur : link");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could really do with being a bit more specific - what is it you'd like explaining.

Comment: @AveryPayne useless comment

Comment: Fine, comment removed.  Although I think it was 100% topical.  My C isn't the best in the world, but it looks like a rather half-baked attempt at doing parallel C compilation with gcc using the program's command line arguments as a list of files to compile.  Which is strange, given that `make` can do parallel compilation. (see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html )